# Drop down menus not working with % width

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a nav menu that i want the width to be dynamic but the nested ***ul li*** & ***ul li a*** are throwing up errors.

Everything works fine aside from the width attribute:

When I have: ***#menu ul li {width: 19%;}*** and ***#menu {width:45%;}***

the drop down menu will not display correctly.

But when I change the width using: ***#menu ul li a {width: 160px;}*** and ***#menu {width:800px;}***

it does show correctly.

I want it to go by % as it works with the rest of my page and with the smaller screens using @media.

Here is the code with the figures set to %:

```
    <style>
    #menu {
    padding-top: 135px;
    width: 45%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 30px;
    }

    #menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

    #menu ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 19%;
    }

    #menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    #menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 31px;
    }

    #menu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="menu">      
    <ul><li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li></ul>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="whoweare.html">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="whatwedo.html">What We Do</a></li>
                <li><a href="philosophy.html">Our Philosophy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>    
     </ul>

     <ul><li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li></ul>

     <ul><li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li></ul> 

     <ul><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li></ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: you can use `%` but it should be exact so that text in it don't overlap in if it overlap you can change the layout of menu like i have done check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ka3z1Ldt/

Answer (score 0):

Best option is instead of  **`%`** - use `javascript` or `JQuery` for this issue (**It should Responsive Design to run smoothly on any Device**).

- **Put below code into `<head>` tag of your HTML page**

`<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var w = window.innerWidth;
            var h = window.innerHeight;
            if (w > 320 && w < 650) {
                //aplly css for  mobile
            }
            else {
                //apply css for desktop 
            }
        });
    </script>`